# NodeJS: Fetching Data whenever the server starts

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to Node and async programming. I'm building a website in which I have to fetch some data from external websites and show it to client(AngularJS Client).
**What I want to do is that whenever my server starts, it should fetch data from the external websites and place it in DB.**

I have following code in my **server.js** file:

```js
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    abc = require('./server/controllers/abc');

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('I\'m listening...');
});

app.on('listening', function(){
  abc.visitPages;
});
```

and following snippet in **abc.js**:

```js
module.exports.visitPages = function () {
  console.log('Going to visitPages');
}
```

my server works fine but it does not go to the **visitPages()** function in **abc.js**  any help in this regard would be very kind.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you want to fetch it every time the server starts? Don't you want to fetch it periodically?

Comment: well actually I do want to fetch it periodically as long as the server is running. any suggestions about that? @ExplosionPills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you're actually running the function. Unlike some other languages, you must provide the parentheses to signify that the function should be invoked in javascript.

Use `abc.visitPages()` inside your listen callback.

Also, I'm not sure `app.on('listener')` will ever fire. Looks like express doesn't [support it](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2339). I would move the method call into your `app.listen()` callback instead.

```
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('I\'m listening...');
  abc.visitPages();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want, note that there is no event called `listening`, you have to emit it

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    abc = require('./server/controllers/abc');

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('I\'m listening...');
    app.emit('listening'); // <-- just emit this event
});

app.on('listening', function() {
    abc.visitPages(); // <-- call function
});

//alternate
app.on('listening', abc.visitPages);
```

Comment: You could probably just do `abc.visitPages()` on its own (or at least once the DB is ready)

Comment: @ExplosionPills made some changes, what you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call you function .

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
abc = require('./server/controllers/abc');
abc.visitPages();

app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('I\'m listening...');
call_my_function();
});
```